# Maior e menor valor de cada linha do array bidimensional

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando obter o menor e o maior valor de cada linha em um array bidimensional com java, porém estou obtendo os valores incorretos. Segue o código:

```
int[][] arrayValues = {
    { 21, 33, 70, 16, 70, 80, 67, 21 },
    { 54, 93, 36, 80, 48, 41, 14, 5 },
    { 6, 91, 81, 14, 37, 91, 98, 35 },
    { 51, 20, 54, 46, 59, 72, 65, 79 },
    { 4, 34, 95, 74, 14, 61, 94, 68 }
};

int min = arrayValues[0][0];
int max = arrayValues[0][0];
int[] minValue = new int[arrayValues.length];
int[] maxValue = new int[arrayValues.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayValues[i].length; j++) {
        if (arrayValues[i][j] < min) {
            minValue[i] = arrayValues[i][j];
        }

        if (arrayValues[i][j] > max) {
            maxValue[i] = arrayValues[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Min: " + minValue[i] + " Max: " + maxValue[i]);
}
```

Os valores mínimos retornados são: 16, 14, 14, 20 e 14 e os máximos: 67, 50, 35, 79 e 68, porém os mínimos deveriam ser: 16, 14, 6, 20 e 14 e os máximos: 80, 93, 98, 79 e 95. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, já que em algumas linhas ele obtem o valor correto.

Comment: Sevocê quer o maior e menor **de cada linha** use `for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) { int min = arrayValues[i][0]; int max = arrayValues[i][0]; for (int j = 0; j < arrayValues[i].length; j++) {` e não uma única vez para todo o array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O anônimo, [em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494928/maior-e-menor-valor-de-cada-linha-do-array-bidimensional#comment919279_494928), matou a charada do que está acontecendo. Você precisa isolar os mínimos e máximos para para cada índice `i`. Também é necessário atualizar os valores de `max` e `min` nos *loops* internos (veja [a resposta do Bernardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494938/100)).

Dito isso, você pode usar *streams* para conseguir o mesmo resultado, o que simplifica bastante o código:

```
Arrays.stream(arrayValues)
    .map(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
    .map(s -> s.summaryStatistics())
    .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("Min: %02d Max: %02d\n", e.getMin(), e.getMax()));
```

#### [Veja funcionando no ideone.com](https://ideone.com/zAWR4b)

A primeira linha converte a matriz para uma *stream* de *arrays* de inteiros.
A segunda linha converte cada *array* de inteiros (i.e., cada linha da matriz) em uma [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).
A terceira linha obtém um objeto [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) contendo estatísticas de cada *stream* interna.
Finalmente a última linha imprime o mínimo e o máximo de cada `IntSummaryStatistics`.

#### Saída:

```
Min: 16 Max: 80
Min: 14 Max: 93
Min: 06 Max: 98
Min: 20 Max: 79
Min: 04 Max: 95
```

Essa é uma de muitas ocasiões em que a versão funcional é mais sucinta e legível do que a versão imperativa.
A classe `IntSummaryStatistics` certamente está encapsulado parte da complexidade das operações de máximo e mínimo, porém, mesmo que `IntSummaryStatistics` e os métodos `IntStream.min()` /  `IntStream.max()` não existissem ainda seria trivial reduzir a *stream* e obter os resultados manualmente (e.g., `.reduce(Math::min)`). Ao meu ver, mesmo um programador leigo em programação funcional poderá bater o olho no código acima e entender rapidamente que a intenção é calcular mínimos e máximos por linha. Já a versão imperativa pode ser um pouco mais difícil de entender.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Strack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[][] arrayValues = {
            { 21, 33, 70, 16, 70, 80, 67, 21 },
            { 54, 93, 36, 80, 48, 41, 14, 5 },
            { 6, 91, 81, 14, 37, 91, 98, 35 },
            { 51, 20, 54, 46, 59, 72, 65, 79 },
            { 4, 34, 95, 74, 14, 61, 94, 68 }
        };

        int min;
        int max;
        int[] minValue = new int[arrayValues.length];
        int[] maxValue = new int[arrayValues.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
            min = arrayValues[i][0];
            max = arrayValues[i][0];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayValues[i].length; j++) {
                if (arrayValues[i][j] < min) {
                    min = arrayValues[i][j];
                }
                if (arrayValues[i][j] > max) {
                    max = arrayValues[i][j];
                }
            }
            minValue[i] = min;
            maxValue[i] = max;
            System.out.println("Min: " + minValue[i] + " Max: " + maxValue[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Problemas da versão inicial que foram arrumados:

1. Os valores de `min` e `max` devem ser inicializados com o primeiro valor de cada subvetor. Assim evitamos que essas variáveis armazenem valores de subvetores diferentes do atual.
2. No laço interno a comparação deve ser feita com todo o subvetor, e se o valor em `[i][j]` for menor que `min`, `min` é atualizado com o novo valor.
3. Analogamente para computar o máximo, se o valor em `[i][j]` for maior que `max`, `max` passa a ser o novo valor.
4. No fim do *loop* interno, `min` e `max` terão os valores dos mínimos e máximos em cada linha, sendo então atribuídos respectivamente a `minValue[i]` e `maxValue[i]`.

Comment: Espera um momento

Comment: Vou colocar comentarios no codigo